# Read from file without knowing the type

Tags: java, android, methods, types

I am trying to create my first library, and for that I am doing a simple write/read from file library.

For now I have the code for the save methods:

```
@NonNull
public TexterRequest write(List<Object> data) {
    return write(data.toString());
}

@NonNull
public TexterRequest write(String data) {
    return new TexterRequest(context, data);
}
```

For the "write" part, I have different methods that accepts different params. If I want to write a list, it converts this list to a String and then it calls a final "write" method and saves the string to a file.

But what for the "read" method? How could I read a file and return based on the user choose. Something like this:

```
public Object read(String file) {
    File path = context.getFileStreamPath("file" + ".txt");
    if (!path.exists()) return null;
    else return readedFile;
}
```

Then I should read the file like this:

```
String readString = read("myFile") // the method should return a string
List<Object> readList = read("myFile") // the method should return a list
```

Is this possible? What would be the best aproach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the best approach for your use case is to simply have two methods like below. The API would be clear and easy to understand.

```
final String string = readString("myFile") // return type is String
final List<Object> list = readList("myFile") // return type is List<Object> or List<T>

@NonNull
public String readString(@NonNull String fileName) {
    // Implementation
    return string;
}

@NonNull
public List<Object> readList(@NonNull String fileName) {
    final String string = readString(fileName);
    // Parsing logic to convert to a List
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Ah.. I was really hoping to make things simple by having a single "read" method. But I don't think this is possible right now. Having no other alternatives I will accept your answer. Thank you!